# Denormalization practices in reactive application

Tags: mongodb, meteor, rxjs, observable

I am creating a reactive application with Meteor (with MongoDB as a backend).

I initially created a non-reactive-aware collection and denormalizers, eg.:

```
class DocCollection extends Mongo.Collection {
  insert(doc, callback) {
    const docId = super.insert(doc, callback);
    doc = docMongo.findOne(docId);  // for illustration, A
    console.log(doc);
    return docId;
  }
}

docMongo = new DocCollection();
```

Now, I'd like to wrap it into `MongoObservable`, which will facilitate listening to the changes to the collection:

```
export const Doc = new MongoObservable.Collection(docMongo);
```

Then, I define a Method:

```
Meteor.methods({
  add_me() {
    Doc.insert(myDoc);
  }
});
```

in `server/main.js` and call it in `app.component.ts`'s constructor:

```
@Component(...)
export class AppComponent {

  constructor() {
    Meteor.call('add_me');
  }
}
```

I get `undefined` printed to console (unless I sleep a little before `findOne`), so I suppose when I was looking for the doc after insertion in my `Mongo.Collection`, the document wasn't yet ready to be searched for.

1. Why does it happen, even though I overwrote the non-reactive class and only then wrapped it in `MongoObservable`?
2. How do I typically do denormalization with a reactive collection? Should I pass observables to my denormalizers and there create new ones, or is it possible to nicely wrap the non-reactive code afterwards (like I tried and failed above)? Note that I don't want to directly pass `doc` inside, as in more complex scenarios it will cause other inserts/updates elsewhere for which I'd also want to wait.
3. How do people typically test these things? If I run a test, the code above may succeed locally, as db insertion time is small, but fail when the delay is higher.

Comment: Please add some context where you exactly call the insert function otherwise it's hard to reason about.

Comment: Added more context. Thank you for taking a look.

Comment: I am not sure if you overcomplicate things here, there are great packages for hooking into the mongo `insert` `update` and `remove` methods. I think this will be more suited in order to decouple this from internal collection code (you access an instance within a class definition). If you definitely have to use the code this way, please explain a bit more.

Comment: The way I'm doing it above is a suggested way in [meteor guide](https://guide.meteor.com/v1.4/collections.html#abstracting-denormalizers). Can you offer an alternative?